# Getting value instead of name on pie chart in Java

Tags: java, jfreechart

```
package charts;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class Pie {

    public void DrawChart() {
        DefaultPieDataset pieDataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();

        pieDataSet.setValue("C", new Integer(10));

        pieDataSet.setValue("C++", new Integer(20));

        pieDataSet.setValue("JAVA", new Integer(50));

        pieDataSet.setValue("C#", new Integer(40));

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("MY CHART",
            pieDataSet, false, false, true);

        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Usage Trend", chart);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pie pie = new Pie();

        pie.DrawChart();
    }
}
```

The above code will generate a pie chart with slices as "C, C++, Java and C#" but I want to display the values instead of name.

What modifications should I do?

Comment: Presumably you want to specify the name *somewhere* - otherwise no-one will know what the numbers mean. Please clarify.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
pieDataSet.setValue("50", new Integer(50));
```

or

```
pieDataSet.setValue("Java(50)", new Integer(50));
```

or

```
pieDataSet.setValue("Java[50]", new Integer(50));
```

or

```
pieDataSet.setValue("Java:50", new Integer(50));
```

---

Another method would be to enable ToolTips using

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("MY CHART", 
                     pieDataSet, false, true, true);
```

ToolTips shows both the name and the value.

Comment: if i make the third paramter in ChartFactory.createPieChart3D as true...the name will appear as legend...i want only number to indicate.....

Comment: 3rd parameter is legend, 4th parameter is tooltip

Comment: Do you only want numbers in the legend?

Comment: legend shoud be at bottom indicating color.....number should be pointing to slice.....

Comment: Hi.....one more question....is their a way that we can populate pie chart dynamically.... that based on the values got from database...can any one guide me...?

Answer (score 2):

> I want value part separately, along key as legend.

You can use [`StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html).

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setLegendLabelGenerator(new
    StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0}: {2}"));
```

Comment: No problem: Please consider clicking the gray check mark on the left to accept this answer.

Comment: @user654761 Also see `plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0}: {2}"));`